# Finding endpoints and its mapping

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I wanted to create a report that should contain all the Azure Private Endpoints and to which specific resource type it is attached to. Is there a command-line way to figure this out? so that I can add them in my scripting to make the report?

Answer (score 0):

If by "attached to", you're referring to the service connection, you can try:

```
az network private-endpoint list | 
  ConvertFrom-Json | 
  Select -Expand privateLinkServiceConnections
```

in which the `privateLinkServiceId` would contain the resource ID, which might contain the type you're looking for.